# I cannot read the data I uploaded to firebase in fragment A, in fragment B

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

As seen in the codes, I cannot read the data I uploaded to Firebase in another fragment. It says data is empty. But the data is visible in firebase. My Firebase path and the names where I save the data are correct. When I try it, data up to control 2 comes. But control 3 and later are not read. Why is my data showing empty? Can you help with this?

Fragment-A where I upload data to firebase

```
yaklasanetkinliklist = hashMapOf<String, String>()


yaklasanetkinliklist.put("gunid",dateday)
yaklasanetkinliklist.put("adsoyadid",adsoyad.text.oString())
yaklasanetkinliklist.put("cepnoid", cepno.text.toString())
yaklasanetkinliklist.put("aciklamaid", aciklamano.text.toString())


firestore2.collection("511").document(yeardate).collection(monthdate).add(yaklasanetkinliklist).addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(context,"başarılı",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               

            }.addOnFailureListener {


                Toast.makeText(context,"başarszz", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
```

Fragment-B where I am trying to read data from firebase

```
firestoree.collection("511").document(yeardate).collection(monthdate).get().addOnSuccessListener {

        if(it != null){
            Toast.makeText(context,"control 2" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            if(!it.isEmpty){
                Toast.makeText(context,"control 3" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                ev1yaklasanetkinliklist.clear()


                for(document in it){

                    var gunidd=document.get("gunid") as String
                    var cepid=document.get("cepnoid") as String
                    var adidd=document.get("adsoyadid") as String
                    var aciklamaid=document.get("aciklamaid") as String

                    val deger1= YaklasanEtkinlik(gunidd,adidd,cepid,aciklamaid)
                    ev1yaklasanetkinliklist.add(deger1)


                    Toast.makeText(context,"başarılı" + " :  " + gunidd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: In fragment A, I save the data to firebase. B or C. Doesn't matter. I cannot retrieve the data I saved in these fragments. It keeps saying empty data. But the data is there. When I try to get the data in fragment A, I can read the data. But I cannot read data in another fragment.

Comment: When you try to read the data, is any of the Toast messages even displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`if (it.data != null)`

or

`if (it.result != null)`

where you use `if (!it.isEmpty)`